# VB6 - How to detect a file is finished copying from an external source

Tags: vb6, samba, file-copying

My software (written in VB6) needs to import csv files that can be large. Users are using copy/paste to place the files in the input folder.
**How can I be sure the files I want to read are fully copied before processing them?**

Things I tried :

- Compare GetFileSizeString over a span of seconds : doesn't work, I get the final value even if the file has just begun to copy.
- FileSystemObject.DateLastModified : same
- FileSystemObject.DateLastAccessed : same
- FileLen : same
- FileDateTime : same

> **EDIT - Added Samba/Linux Info (from comments):**

*I'm having a hard time dealing with is from Samba/Linux. I don't know why, but when the file is copied by Samba, the read only attribute doesn't matter.*

Comment: Maybe try opening the file as read only. I'd expect the copying process would have the file open as read-write, so opening as read only should fail. Retry until the open succeeds (when the copy is complete).

Comment: This works with Windows, but sadly the case I'm having a hard time dealing with is from Samba/Linux. I don't know why, but when the file is copied by Samba, the read only attribute doesn't matter.

Comment: You could investigate subscribing to Directory Change Notifications (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365261(v=vs.85).aspx), or interfacing to Change Journals (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363798(v=vs.85).aspx).  But I don't know if either one of those will provide positive notification as to when the copy operation has finished.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this method which uses the API to test for exclusive access. I've never tried it on a platform other than Windows so, I guess result may vary. I use this in a module of frequently used methods, but I believe I have included the API calls, types, and constants used.

```
Private Const ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION = 32&
Private Const GENERIC_WRITE = &H40000000
Private Const INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE = -1
Private Const OPEN_EXISTING = 3

Private Type SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
    nLength As Long
    lpSecurityDescriptor As Long
    bInheritHandle As Long
End Type

Private Declare Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hObject As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function CreateFile Lib "kernel32" Alias "CreateFileA" (ByVal lpFileName As String, ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long, ByVal dwShareMode As Long, lpSecurityAttributes As SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, ByVal dwCreationDisposition As Long, ByVal dwFlagsAndAttributes As Long, ByVal hTemplateFile As Any) As Long

Public Function CanOpenExclusive(ByVal vFileName As String) As Boolean
    Dim lngResult As Long
    Dim udtSA As SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES

    On Error GoTo errCanOpenExclusive

    If Len(vFileName) > 0 Then
        udtSA.nLength = Len(udtSA)
        udtSA.bInheritHandle = 1&
        udtSA.lpSecurityDescriptor = 0&
        lngResult = CreateFile(vFileName, GENERIC_WRITE, 0&, udtSA, OPEN_EXISTING, 0&, 0&)
        If lngResult <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE Then
            Call CloseHandle(lngResult)
            CanOpenExclusive = True
        Else
            Select Case Err.LastDllError  'some errors may indicate the file exists, but there was an error opening it
                Case Is = ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION
                    CanOpenExclusive = False

                Case Else
                    GoTo errCanOpenExclusive
           End Select
        End If
    End If

    Exit Function

errCanOpenExclusive:
    Err.Raise Err.Number, Err.Source & ":CanOpenExclusive", Err.Description

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the FileDateTime function to work with to calculate when a date/time value indicating the date and time that a file was created or last modified.

You can read up more on the file system usage [HERE](http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/working-file-system-vb6).

> In the syntax above, pathname is a string expression specifying a valid path (it may optionally include the drive); drive is a string expression specifying a drive letter; and filespec, oldfilespec, and newfilespec are string expressions that specify a file (they may optionally include the drive and path).
>
> Following is a set of functions that can be used with files (all are functions except SetAttr, which is a statement):
>
> Function
>
> Description
>
> Syntax
>
> FileDateTime
>
> Returns a date/time value indicating the date and time that a file was created or last modified.
>   FileDateTime(filespec)
>
> GetAttr
>   Returns an integer representing the attributes of a file, directory, or folder
>   GetAttr(filespec)
>
> SetAttr
>   Statement that lets you specify the attributes for a file
>   SetAttr(filespec, attributes)
>
> CurDir$ (or CurDir)
>   Returns a string that indicates the current path for a specified disk drive. In the syntax on the right, drivename is a string expression that specifies a valid disk drive designation
>
> CurDir$(drivename)
>   Dir$ (or DIr)
>   Returns a string that indicates a file or directory matching specified conditions
>   Dir$(filespec [,attributes])
>
> FileLen
>   Returns a Long specifying the length of a file in bytes. If the specified file is open when the FileLen function is called, the value returned represents the size of the file immediately before it was opened.
>   FileLen(pathname)
>
> LOF
>   Returns a Long representing the size, in bytes, of a file opened using the Open statement.
>   FileLen(filenumber)